# Set gamma with pygame 2.0.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I create a game and I would like to set the gamma of the screen. For example:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 450))
font = pygame.font.SysFont('consolas', 25)

red   = 1
green = 1
blue  = 1

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((20, 20, 20))
    
    # draw colored zones
    for x in range(600):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (x * 255 / 600, 0, 0), (x, 0), (x, 100))
    for x in range(600):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, x * 255 / 600, 0), (x, 100), (x, 200))
    for x in range(600):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, x * 255 / 600), (x, 200), (x, 300))

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if y < 100:
            red   = x / 300
            pygame.display.set_gamma(red, green, blue)
        elif y < 200:
            green = x / 300
            pygame.display.set_gamma(red, green, blue)
        elif y < 300:
            blue  = x / 300
            pygame.display.set_gamma(red, green, blue)

    text = 'pygame.display.set_gamma(%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)' % (red, green, blue)
    text = font.render(text, 0, (255, 255, 255), True)
    screen.blit(text, (10, 440 - text.get_height())) # render the text

    pygame.display.flip()
```

But when I updated my pygame version to 2.0.0.dev6, the gamma correction didn't work, and I saw ugly colors, blue and yellow flashing irregularly.

I'm on Windows 10.

#### EDIT 1

After investigation, the green color seems not to be handled by the `set_gamma` function. When I change x value in the color `(0, x * 255 / 600, 0)`, nothing happens.

#### EDIT 2

I now have the latest `pygame` version - now litteraly *nothing* happens.
According to the documentation,

> Not all systems and hardware support gamma ramps

Ok! Maybe my computer doesn't handle this function! But:

> if the function succeeds it will return True.

And I get `True`, even if nothing works as expected.
Does someone see clearly in this mess of bugs?

Comment: If you actually *updated* pygame in the correct way, then there should be no older pygame version existing for you to either keep or remove. As [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) says: `The best way to install pygame is with the pip tool (which is what python uses to install packages).` Correspondingly, the expected way to update it is to use the `--upgrade` flag for `pip`.

Comment: I now have the latest pygame version. Now, this bug has been fixed, but... nothing happens when I call `pygame.display.set_gamma`. As the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_gamma) says about `set_gamma`, 1.0 is the normal gamma value. So it doesn't range from 0 to 255 as I thought. But nothing happens at all, with any value. How does it work for you? Does the problem come from my computer?

Comment: What happens if you set gamma *before* drawing the lines? Also, how exactly are you expecting things to change visually? Also, you should ask a new question for all of this.

Comment: I think [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_gamma) can help me: *"Not all systems and hardware support gamma ramps"* -- edit: but *"if the function succeeds it will return True."* > it does nothing but I get True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I help develop pygame.

Thank you for reporting this, I believe this is a bug in pygame.

I could replicate everything you said except for `display.set_gamma()` returning `True` even when it succeeded. For me it always returned `False`.

That difference aside, I found the source of the bug in the pygame source code, and submitted a patch to fix it. https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2524

Assuming that this gets merged, the bug will be fixed in pygame 2.0.2.

But you want your code to work ASAP presumably, so you have a couple options.

- Downgrade to pygame 1.9.6 for now, then upgrade to 2.0.2 once it comes out.
- Build pygame from source on windows (sorta difficult)
- If you happen to be on Python 3.8 64bit, I can send you a `wheel` file of pygame 2.0.2.dev1 to pip install from.

Edit: I just realized you posted this in August. Sorry this took so long. If you have an issue like this in the future, pygame's issue tracker on github is the place to go to report this stuff: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues